# How to install and run project in github

Tags: reactjs

Im a newbie in Reactjs. I get project from github but cant run it though i `npm install` and `npm run build` it. Here is the project i try to install in my computer: https://github.com/iuliaL/diagonistician-ReactJS-Express-Mongoose-RestAPI

Thank you very much, << sorry but stackoverflow doesnt allow me post this question so i type some line >>

Comment: Rather than trying to workaround the system, try following the guidelines of the site :) Add some code, expand a little bit on what you tried, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try to follow these steps.

1. Git clone... `git clone https://github.com/iuliaL/diagonistician-ReactJS-Express-Mongoose-RestAPI.git`
2. Enter into project directory... `cd diagonistician-ReactJS-Express-Mongoose-RestAPI`
3. Install npm dependancy `npm install`
4. start npm server `npm run build`

that's all. Now browse to localhost: on browser.